# Solving this Equation with Complex Numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Can someone help me solve the following equation?

$$ 3z^3 + 2z^2 = 6z-4 $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(z)=3z^3+2z^2-6z+4$, then $P(-2)=0$ so you can factorize $P$; thus, you only have to solve an equation of degree two.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation has $z=-2$ as one of its roots. You should be able to take it from there.